# How to make python search the entire HDD

Tags: python, search

I'm making a simple python search program for my computer and I was wondering how I would get it to scan the entire C Drive to search for a file, instead of the file being in the same folder as the target file? This is what I have so far.

---

```
import os

print('What song would you like to listen to?')
choice = input().title()
os.startfile(choice + '.mp3')
```

Comment: I doubt you want to scan the entire C drive, anyway. Since that's where all the system directories are. You probably want to limit it to your user directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a root directory to search within, you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk). It will yield triples of directory paths, directories within that directory, and filenames within that directory. For example, if we have this directory structure:

```
root
├── dir1
│   └── file1
├── dir2
│   └── subdir
│       ├── file1
│       ├── file2
│       └── file3
├── file1
└── file2
```

Then this code:

```
for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('root'):
    print((path, dirnames, filenames))
```

Will print:

```
('root', ['dir1', 'dir2'], ['file1', 'file2'])
('root/dir1', [], ['file1'])
('root/dir2', ['subdir'], [])
('root/dir2/subdir', [], ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'])
```

So if you’re looking for a `file3`, you just keep looping until you see a `file3` in `filenames` ([the `in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) would be appropriate here). Once you see it, the full path to the file is `os.path.join(path, 'file3')`, which you should be able to open with `os.startfile`.

Comment: @Cailimb: Without completely giving away the answer, I’ve added a little more detail showing what `os.walk` will give you by means of an example. Hopefully that will help you get on the right track.

Comment: Not sure if this is a simple task or not, but I can't figure it out?

Comment: @Cailimb: It’s kind of difficult to assist without knowing where the problem lies. If you’re stuck on checking membership, you can use [the `in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

Answer (score 0):

Use the file and directory operations available in the **os** module. Visit the following portion of the Python docs for reference:
**https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os-file-dir**

Note that you can't extract meta data from files using these methods, so you'll have to depend on the player to do that.

Cheers,

-=Cameron